# Looking for the origin of custom to decorate the Aron Hakodesh with 10 Commandments

Tags: sources-mekorot, synagogue, aseres-hadibros, ark-aron-kodesh

Many synagogues have the custom to decorate the Peroches (curtain covering the Ark) with imagery of the 10 Commandments or Luchos in some form.

When did this custom originate?

Is there any source for this in halachic/kabbalistic writings?

Comment: R' Moshe Shternbuch discusses the minhag here (https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=442), particularly regarding whether to make the luchos rounded (as seems to be accepted) or squared (as the gemara says the luchos actually were).

Comment: many people know that the Luchot were squared, but say that a rounded one looks more physically appealing